# Continuation style call like .NET async-await in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, async-await, future, continuations

I'm working on a `C++` project where I have to implement code some `custom radio communication`.

This obviously cannot block the main thread at any point by waiting for a `join(), a Future.get()` etc. , but I'm really struggling to figure out how to do this without getting into thread hell with `mutex` locking all over the place to cripple the performance.

Is there any easy way to do this like `aync-await` in `.NET`?

The `architecture of the program` is basically like this:

```
int main()
{
   App = new APP();
   Ui = new UI();
   Statemachine = new StateMachine(); 

   for(;;)
   {
      App->update();
   }
}

// The update fucntion of the App class
App::update()
{
   Ui-> update();
   Statemachine->CurrentState->update();;
}

// The update function of the state machine
CurrentState::update()
{
   // Must not block thread 
   string receivedText = Radio->GetDatafromslowRadioAsync();

   // Immediately continue to execute this
   ImportantFunction();
   AnotherImportantFucntion();
}
```

As of now the radio runs in a separate thread, continuously sending messages from a queue that can be filled from the main thread.

Comment: The same way it works under the hood in .NET: you have to make the thread performing computation to signal UI thread somehow to update the UI. Exact implementation depends on your UI framework (e.g. for Qt it would probably be slots+signals)..

Comment: I want to schedule a function to run on another thread, then add a continuation to be used as callback when the thread is ready with the data at some arbritrary point in time. There is no UI framework, I'm asking for a way to do this with standard C++ threading/async features

Comment: current clang supports the compiler flag `-fcoroutines-ts` which enables coroutines. They should appear in standard c++ in c++23 but they way things are going they will be 'standard in wild well before then'

Comment: Unfortunately, the authors of the C++ standard library seem to shy away from providing standard ways to do anything that you could write for yourself so, no `std::thread_pool`, no `std::future`, etc. You can get stuff like that from the [Boost library](https://www.boost.org/), but I'm not qualified to give you any answers from Boost.

Comment: There's a huge difference between could write and should write. If the authors didn't think we could handle semaphores then why they think we can handle stuff like this is beyond me. That said I have no clue whatsoever on how to properly write a generic function that implements continuation, so any suggestions are welcome